# Bash variable parameter expansions complete documentation

Tags: bash

There are some lesser known bash variable expansions:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|                       description                        |   expression   |
+----------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
| Remove everything **after** the **last** '7'             | ${var%7*}      |
| Remove everything **after** the **first** '7'            | ${var%%7*}     |
| Remove everything **before** the **first** '7'           | ${var#*7}      |
| Remove everything **before** the **last** '7'            | ${var##*7}     |
| First char upper case                                    | ${var^}        |
| All upper case                                           | ${var^^}       |
| First char lower case                                    | ${var,}        |
| All lower case                                           | ${var,,}       |
| Show how variable was set                                | ${var@A}       |
| ?? something cool ??                                     | ${var@E}       |
| Print variable as though it were the prompt variable PS1 | ${var@P}       |
| ?? something cool ??                                     | ${var@Q}       |
+----------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

I have been struggling to find a source that documents all of these tricks. So far the best one I have found is this cheat sheet. But even that page is missing some of these expansion rules. For the purposes of writing good bash code, and making that code portable I am looking for several things:

1. What are all of the bash variable expansion tricks?
2. Where is there a document that shows all of them (with examples ideally)?
3. What versions of bash do which tricks work with?

Comment: `man bash` documents all of these, except the documentation does not have any examples and is written in really technical language.

Comment: My answer becomes a 'community wiki', so it's open to grow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some good pointers on *parameter expansions*:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html
- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073
- https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

You missed many, like

- single substitution a -> b : `${x/a/b}`
- multiple substitutions a -> b : `${x//a/b}`
- offset manipulation: `${x:1:3}`
- `${var-word}` if var is defined, use var; otherwise, "word"
- `${var+word}` if var is defined, use "word"; otherwise, nothing
- `${var=word}` if var is defined, use var; otherwise, use "word" AND also assign "word" to var
- `${var?error}` if var is defined, use var; otherwise print "error" and exit
- array slice `${files[@]: -4}`

Note that most of PE works with array too

Comment: I also like Advanced Bash-Scripting's [Parameter Substitution section](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)